# Получение именем столбцов результата запроса

Tags: c#, mysql

Добрый день!
Создаю подключение к базе MySQL, получаю результат.
Я знаю как получить значения результата (`result.GetString(NNN)`), а вот имени колонок не понимаю как получить.

Вот код:

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(current_connectionstring);
MySqlDataReader myreader;

//открываем соединение:
string SQLstring = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tbNameTableInDB.Text);

                        MySqlCommand MC = new MySqlCommand(SQLstring, connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        myreader = MC.ExecuteReader();

                        //1 получаем колонки и загружаем их в ТЧ на форме
                        result_querry.Columns.Clear();

                        if (myreader.HasRows)
                        {
                            int ConumnIndex = 1;

                            while (ConumnIndex <= (myreader).FieldCount)
                            {
                              //код получения имено колонки
                                ConumnIndex++;

                                //добавление непосредственно нашей колонки в саму ТЧ
                           DataGridViewTextBoxColumn d = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                           d.Name = currentColumnName;
                           d.HeaderText = currentColumnName;

                            result_querry.Columns.Add(d);
                            }
    }
```

Я хочу получить имена колонок из запрос и создать аналогичные в `GridView`, а потом загрузить туда значения.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить запросом имена колонок?**

Comment: Первое что пришло в голову:)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table_name`
LIMIT 0, 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount;i++)
{
    string nextColumnName = myReader.GetName(i);
}
```

Comment: И ещё, незакрытый `DataReader` или `Connection` - грубая ошибка. Всегда помещайте их использование в блок using

Answer (score 2):

Например, из таблицы [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: т.е. нужно выполнить еще 1 запрос  - запрос на получение имен колонок из схемы ?

Comment: @chudo116, "Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить запросом имена колонок?" - мне казалось Вы это и спрашивали :)